# Can I get user id via Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm using Instagram Graph API and getting some data.
Actually, this data is too few.
I want to get an user ID for an unique user, but this API doesn't include an user ID.
How do I get this value?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram Graph API actually returns user ID. Please have a look into the reference for the user object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user

You can either use the `id` field for unique user ID from Instagram Graph API or you can use `ig_id`. The latter is the ID that was used in legacy Instagram API.

Comment: This API is only for `an Instagram Business Account or an Instagram Creator Account`.
I'm using this Instagram Graph API(Hashtag Search): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media

Does this API return a user ID?

Comment: @tadamw You didn't mention Hashtag search in your original questions. In such case it's not possible. Here is the list of the fields that can be returned for hashtag search: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media#returnable-fields 
This information is also listed in limitations:
- You cannot request the username field on returned media objects.
- Responses will not include any personally identifiable information.